# Where to add a source covering multiple topics in documentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

There are multiple topics covered in [Excel-VBA Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/topics)  called [Debugging and Troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting#t=201701151957195070192).

Topics like:

- Debug.Print
- Locals Window
- etc.

Seeing this, I remembered I saw a great article by [Chip Pearson on debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). It covers pretty much all topics, and maybe some more.

What is a best practice to share this information here on SO?

- Do I add relevant parts of the Chip's article to *all* individual topics that could benefit from it and link to original source?
- Do I add the link to Introduction section of the Docs? At the time this question is asked, the section is empty.
- Do I create another topic and play in my own sandbox?
- Should there be a new feature "Sources" in Documentation?

Thanks for guidance.

Comment: The larger question that occurs to me is why we don't have all VBA documentation in a single place, under the VBA tag. Do we really need to separate out Excel VBA, Word VBA, PowerPoint VBA, Access VBA, etc.? There are far more similarities than there are differences.

Comment: @CodyGray, I totally agree with you. I think that what you are saying is, as you said, "larger" *another* "question".

Comment: Seems like Remarks is an appropriate place, as you are making a remark about where to find additional information... I'd probably keep it only on the topics specifically about debugging though.